# NextJS share data per request

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, next.js13

What I need is request context, accessible from everywhere I want per request (only server).

For example I have global map of instances.

```
class RequestInstance {
    private _data = "";

    public doSomething() {
        this._data = "whatever";
    }
    public getSomething() {
        return this._data;
    }
}

export const GlobalInstances = new Map<number, RequestInstance>;
```

Implement these functions (I dont know where, mby middleware):

```
function onBeginRequest(request: any) {
    GlobalInstances.set(request.id, new RequestInstance());
}

function onEndRequest(request: any) {
    GlobalInstances.delete(request.id);
}
```

Now use this instance everywhere I want within current request. (on server)

```
export default function Layout({children}: {children: React.ReactNode}) {
    const id = currentRequest.getId(); // I dont know how
    const instance = GlobalInstances.get(id);
    instance.getSomething();
    instance.doSomething();
    
    return children;
}
```

Its only my idea how can I share request specific data (context).

Is anybody know how can I solve this issue?

Use Next.Js 14.0.4.

Comment: A request is stateless, it's lifetime is very short.   Could you explain at a higher level what it is your trying to do...

Comment: I want share data for one request. I have lot of data logics depend on request and I want use this logics everywhere in app on server

Comment: I mean it is not about call api to fetch any data, I need this fetch (cache) feature on normal create instances within one request (node request, get page,...).